# sstabeloader in apache cassandra 4.0 is using 9042 transport port even after overriding it with the "-p" option

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-4.0

The command line used is:
~/apache-cassandra-4.0.1/bin/sstableloader -d 10.14.20.148 -cph 1 -idct 0 -p 9942 -ssp 7011 -sp 7010 --verbose ~/cassandra4_experiment/nishant/employee/

Notice that transport port given is 9942 but I am still seeing that call is made to /10.14.20.148:9042. Any help is appreciated on this.

Comment: There is no port field in the NativeSSTableLoaderClient class in cassandra 4.0 unlike previous versions. I could see below in 4.0:
 int broadcastPort = endpoint.getBroadcastSocketAddress().getPort();
 // use port from broadcast address if set.
 int portToUse = broadcastPort != 0 ? broadcastPort : storagePort; addRangeForEndpoint(range,InetAddressAndPort.getByNameOverrideDefaults(endpoint.getAddress().getHostAddress(), portToUse));

Shouldn't the call "endpoint.getBroadcastSocketAddress().getPort()" return 9942 which is mentioned under the "native_transport_port" field in cassandra.yaml?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cassandra folks changed sstableloader heavily in 4.0.

Currently it parses both `-p` and `-sp` options (native and storage ports), but doesn't use them as documented and expected.

1. Native port (`-p` option) is simply ignored. The way to pass the custom port is `-d host1:native_port1,host2:native_port2,...`. So, your command should look like

```
sstableloader -d 10.14.20.148:9942 ...
```

My guess is that they try to unify the endpoint format across all client tools.

2. Storage port (`-sp` option) is a longer story.
   On startup sstableloader connects to the given Cassandra cluster, takes its broadcast address and storage port and uses them. Only if Cassandra cluster has no `broadcast_address` in its configuration file (`$CASSANDRA_HOME/conf/cassandra.yaml`), sstableloader defaults to the storage port, passed as an option. See details in [CASSANDRA-14522](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-14522).